# How to get all project tags using WandB API from a nested method/function?

Tags: api, tags, wandb

How can I use the WandB API to get all the tags associated with a project in a nested method or function?

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
runs = api.runs(path=f"{entity}/{project}")
tags = []
for run in tqdm(runs): 
    tags.extend(run.tags)

list(set(tags))
```

However, I want to embed this code within a larger function or method. Can someone provide an example of how to achieve this?